# Field being split on input, not output

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently using this function

```
public $year;
public $month;
public $day;

protected function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind();

    $dob = explode('/', $this->dob);
    $this->year = $dob[0];
    $this->month = $dob[1];
    $this->day = $dob[2];

    return $this;
}

protected function beforeSave() {
    $this->dob = $this->year .'/'. $this->month .'/'. $this->day;
}

<div class="col-md-2 dayForm noPadding"> 
<?php
echo $form->textFieldGroup(
    $user, 
    'day', 
    array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'DD'
            )
        )
    )
);
?> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 monthForm ">
<?php
echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
    $user,
    'month',
    array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'data' => array('01' => 'January' , '02' => 'February' , '03' => 'March' , '04' => 'April' , '05' => 'May' , '06' => 'June' , '07' =>'July' , '08' =>'August' , '09' =>'September' , '10' =>'October' , '11' =>'November' , '12' =>'December'),
            // 'data' => 'Jan','Feb';
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'col-md-3 ',
                'prompt' => 'Choose month',
            ),
        )
    )
);
?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 yearForm noPadding"> 
<?php
echo $form->textFieldGroup(
    $user, 
    'year', 
    array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'YYYY',
                'class' => 'col-md-3',
            )
        )
    )
);
?> 
</div>
```

to split up the date of birth field into 3 separate fields. Simple right, user inputs the day, month and year it and goes in the correct format. The issue I'm having is that when the user goes to update the entire dob field is displayed all in the year textfieldgroup, not so good.

How do I explode it back on the way out so all the corresponding fields appear in their textfieldgroups / dropdownlist group?

Comment: remove `return $this;` in after find also put `parent::afterFind()` at last line of the function

Comment: So remove return $this entirely and add parent::afterfind() at the end? Attempted this and it made no change. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post controller code?

Comment: what in the controller should I be looking for? I have actionCreate, actionView and actionUpdate

Comment: The action in which you are getting issue, i.e. update i think

Comment: It simply displays falsely when being pulled from the database

$this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ));

Is all that exists in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I always try to avoid using `afterFind` as it tends to complicate things making it hard to fix issues like yours. You can usually achieve similar results by adding getters (and optionally setters) like so;

```
protected function getDobParts()
{
    return explode('/', $this->dob);
}
protected function changeDobPart($part, $newValue)
{
    $parts = $this->getDobParts();
    $parts[$part] = $newValue;
    $this->dob = implode('/', $parts);
}
public function getYear()
{
    return $this->getDobParts()[0];
}
public function setYear($value)
{
    $this->changeDobPart(0, $value);
}
public function getMonth()
{
    return $this->getDobParts()[1];
}
public function setMonth($value)
{
    $this->changeDobPart(1, $value);
}
public function getDay()
{
    return $this->getDobParts()[2];
}
public function setMonth($value)
{
    $this->changeDobPart(2, $value);
}
```

Yii will take care of making these getters/setters available as properties automatically (e.g. $class->year).

Your view code should remain the same.

ps. it's usually best practice to return the result of parent methods when overriding them. For instance the last line of `beforeSave()` should usually be `return parent::beforeSave();`. If you fail to do so your class might not even save properly.

Comment: That logic looks good, I am getting an error on this line though, public function getYear()
{
    return $this->getDobParts()[0];
}

Comment: Looks like the code sample ended up with two `setMonth`s, rename the second to `setDay`. If that still doesn't work then would you mind telling me your PHP version? (`php -v`)

Comment: Yeah I fixed that as I saw it, the php version is 5.6.3, and it is still defaulting the dob field to the last field "year"

Comment: Are you sure your date format is yyyy/mm/dd and not something like yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: I should have mentioned, there is no difference between using - or /  when using it inside the functions, it still inputs fine but doesn't matter what I use, it either does not input back into the textifelds or fills it out in the year field.

Comment: You could try making it a bit more robust;

 protected function getDobParts()
 {
  $parts = explode('/', $this->dob);
  if (count($parts) !== 3) {
   throw new \Exception('Date of birth format invalid, expected yyyy/mm/dd');
  }
  return $parts;
 }

If after doing so you don't get an Exception then you're most likely using a different class or year property then we've been playing with in this question.